# How to specify a class to A tag that matches the current angular route

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

how do i put a class on `<A>` tag when the current ngroute matches the a tags href. I know there is ui-active in ui-router but I am using ngroute.

Comment: Have you tried using `ngclass="ctrl.getClass()"` and do the route comparison in your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a github project that addresses your issues.

https://github.com/ionescuvictor/ngRoute-active-directive

```
<a route-active="active" href="/#/Test" ></a>
```

gets transformed into

```
  <a class='active' href="/#/Test"></a>
```